# Send body in PUT request in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to send body in PUT request but the data is not received on backend

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
let putBody = "bucket=\(bucket)&day=\(day)"
request.HTTPBody = putBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            completion(data: data, response: response as! NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error)
       }) 
   })
 task.resume()
```

The value of `bucket (Int)` is `2015040` and `day (String)` is `day27`. I tried making same request in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), the server received body data so there is nothing wrong with the server.

Is there any other way to set body of a request?

**EDIT :**

It's working perfectly if I change request method to POST in my request and server as well. So the question comes down to how to set body in PUT request?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't gotten query(the stuff after `?` in a URL) and body mixed up? To me your `putBody` looks like what is usually passed as the query...

Comment: What is the server expecting? By the way, you should use [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLQueryItem_Class/).

Comment: server expects bucket and day in body of request.

Answer (score 2):

I've just been dealing with this. Had the exact same issue where it was working perfectly fine with POST but not with PUT or PATCH requests. It seems that for PUT and PATCH requests, Swift is picky about the Content-Type header.

So try adding this:

```
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

This will work as long as your body is url style, so like this:

```
key=value&key=value&key=value
```

For those of you using JSON, just use application/json instead for the Content-Type.